# Finding the Lateral Surface Area with Line Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

So my textbook has a challenge problem where it asks to find the surface area of a figure using line integrals. However, I'm not quite sure how it would be accomplished. The problem goes:

The figure below shows a piece of tin that has been cut from a
circular cylinder. The base of the circular cylinder is modeled by
$x^2 +y^2 = 9$. At any point $(x, y)$ on the base, the height of the object is

$$f(x,y) = 1 + \cos\left(\frac{\pi\cdot x}{4}\right).$$

Explain how to use a line integral to find the surface area of the
piece of tin.

I considered converting everything into a parametric equation with variable $t$, and continuing from there. However, I don't think that method is right because then I would end up with the following:

$$f(x(t),y(t)) = 1 + \cos\left(\frac{\pi\cdot x(t)}{4}\right),$$

where $x(t) = 3\cos(t)$, which would result in a function that isn't elementary.

Any ideas?

Edit:
In case you would like to see the actual problem out of the book, here is a link to it:

[Link to problem](https://books.google.com/books?id=zUfAAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1060&lpg=PA1060&dq=a+The+figure+below+shows+a+piece+of+tin+that+has+been+cut+from+a+circular+cylinder.+The+base+of+the+circular+cylinder+is+modeled+by+At+any+point+on+the+base,+the+height+of+the+object&source=bl&ots=6tcbBp16bR&sig=o_qb0WFTiJHPe4iuN4SHPnE86GY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW6teKod3TAhUC4yYKHSKsCy0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=a%20The%20figure%20below%20shows%20a%20piece%20of%20tin%20that%20has%20been%20cut%20from%20a%20circular%20cylinder.%20The%20base%20of%20the%20circular%20cylinder%20is%20modeled%20by%20At%20any%20point%20on%20the%20base%2C%20the%20height%20of%20the%20object&f=false)

Comment: Well it doesn't say you actually have to solve the integral but describe how a line integral would make it possible

Comment: @Triatticus So are you saying that my approach seems to be correct and that there simply isn't an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the same as @Triatticus. Use $s$, the lenght along the path as independent variable and $f$ in the path as dependent variable. Then, $x(s)=3\sin(s/3)$, etc. Write the integral and you are done.

Comment: I have seen many times before problems in arclength ask for the integral only because solving it would be a tremendous feat. Typically the set up is a very important part as without that you wont even get the right answer. As for integration for a reasonably nice function a numerical method can get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Use $r(t) = \langle 3\cos(t),3\sin(t)\rangle$ and then plug $x(t)=3\cos(t)$ into your $f(x,y)$ equation.

The lateral surface area is the line integral over your given curve, so it would be integral of $f(x,y)\,\mathrm ds$ where $\mathrm ds = || r'(t)||\, dt = 3\, dt$, and $t$ would go from $0$ to $2\pi,$ since it acts like $\theta$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should use Mathjax to format your math text. Use the following link as a reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference